# Cocoa Touch - Color of a round rect button?

Tags: cocoa-touch

Is their anyway to change the white part of a round rect button with out making a custom button?

Answer (score 5):

Well, almost. You have to set it to custom but without subclassing UIButton. Then you should be able to do something like

```
myButton.layer.cornerRadius = 8;
myButton.layer.backgroundColor = [[UIColor blueColor] CGColor];
```

You can also configure the border thickness and color this way. See [CALayer documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CALayer_class/Introduction/Introduction.html) for more details.

Answer (score 4):

i dont know why someone downvoted that answer, it works great, but you gotta add the QuartzCore framework and

```
    #import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>
```

then it works awesome, you lose the sexy highlighting and light sourcing that the roundedrect has, but control over the colour its certainly worth it

Answer (score 3):

As Oliver mentioned, the simplest way to resolve this problem is by creating your own UIButton with custom type

```
// initialize your own UIButton
UIButton *myBtn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
// set background color
[myBtn setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
// set corner radius
myBtn.layer.cornerRadius = 8;
```

Don't forget to import Quartzcore framework in your .m implementation file. Otherwise you won't be able to set the cornerRadius of your custom button.

```
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>
```

Comment: Thanks!  How can I change the backgroundColor when the user presses the button.  Right now the button appears, but does not change state when pressed.